# is there any API to list all the BootVolumes under the root compartment

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

In oracle we have option to create VM in the root account/compartment.
So the boot Volumes create for the above VM will also fall under this root compartment.
Also we have options to terminate this VM leaving behind this bootVolume active.

Exisitng api to list bootVolumes need compartmentId as input, and these bootVolumes don't have any such compartmentId.
Just wanted to know if we have any API's to list all the bootVolumes in the rootCompartment.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to refer to the root compartment in an API or other call, use the tenancy OCID as the compartment OCID.  So, to list all boot volumes in IAD AD2, use;

oci bv boot-volume list --compartment-id ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXh3vXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --availability-domain EXXI:US-ASHBURN-AD-2

Thanks,
Tony